# Regex to validate url

Tags: regex, url

The url will be something like: `meusite.com/user/{keyword here}`

The user will only enter the key word, then I would a regex to validate word if this does not invalidate the URL, blank spaces, special characters and 5 to 22 characters.

Comment: What characters are valid characters for keyword?

Comment: any character that does not break the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want to validate the keyword? Something like this should work:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.\+]{5,22}$/
```

But why not just escape it?

Comment: I do not understand, as well as escape?

Comment: @RidermandeSousaBarbosa: For example, changing spaces to `%20` to make it valid. Why not do that?

Comment: in fact because of the complexity.
Do you have any regex for transform the keyword in a valid url?

Comment: @RidermandeSousaBarbosa: No, why would you do that with regex? What language are you using? PHP offers `urlencode`, JavaScript offers `encodeURIComponent()`...

Comment: There is a method: Url.Encode()
I think it will solve. Thank you. I had not thought of that.